# Taking related rows in a table and creating an array of textboxes for editing and re-submission

Tags: php, arrays, submit

Consider the following table structure: TBL "lease_rates":

```
id   lease_year   classes_letter   lease_rate
01      2010            A              123
02      2010            B              129 
..      2010            E              145
06      2011            A              131
```

etc.

What I want to do is take all of these values and put them into text boxes for editing and re-submission like so:

```
       A     B     C     D     E      
2011  131   ...   ...   ...   ...
2010  123   129   ...   ...   145

      [Add a row]  [Submit Edits]
```

I feel like the first thing I have to do is create an array of values based on lease_year and classes_letter, sort it, and then populate the text boxes.

I'm kinda stuck on how to do this.  Once that's all populated, the submit button needs to update the table with the new values.

I started off here:  http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/10.html  but it didn't help much because I have repeating values that I want to sort by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use three arrays, `$years` (sorted), another `$classes` (sorted) and a last one like this `$arr[$year][$class] = $rate`. Then browse it like this :

```
foreach ($years as $year) {
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        if ($arr[$year][$class] == null) {
            echo '...';
        } else {
            echo $arr[$year][$class];
        }
    }
}
```

And if you need to keep track of its ID, instead of stocking directly the rate in the two dimensional array, store an array, or much better, an object (from something like a LeaseRate class).